# Persistent delayed jobs queue for Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for an existing system to replace an existing slow and complicated self written mechanism of job management.
The existing system:

- 1 MySQL DB with a long massive table of jobs - the queue
- Multiple servers (written in java) all extracting jobs from the queue and processing them
- a job might NOT be deleted from the queue after processing it, to rerun it later
- a job might create other jobs and insert them to the queue

The limitations:

- As more and more jobs are created and inserted in to the queue, it takes longer to extract jobs from it. (The jobs are chosen by priority and type) - create a bottle neck

I'm looking for an existing system that can replace this one, and improve it's performance.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't generally recommend [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service), but it sounds like it really is what you need here. Distributed, transactional, persistent job queue management is what JMS is all about.

Popular open-source implementations include [HornetQ](http://jboss.org/hornetq) and [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- submit your jobs to Amazon's [Simple Queue Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) (maybe JAXB marshalled)
- dynamically start some [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances according to your queue's length and probably
- submit the results (or availability notice for some files on [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) to [Simple Notification Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) (again JAXB marshalled).

That exactly what we do, using [EC2 Spot instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/) to minimize costs. And that's what I call serious cloud computing ;)